# Why are my Woocommerce permalinks conflicting with main website pages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

My current Woocommerce Permalink settings are as follows:

SHOP
[www.mywebsite.com/shop](http://www.mywebsite.com/shop)

SHOP WITH SUB CATEGORY
[www.mywebsite.com/seasons/winter](http://www.mywebsite.com/seasons/winter)

Unfortunately, the above SHOP WITH SUB CATEGORY link also works without the product category - i.e. [www.mywebsite.com/winter](http://www.mywebsite.com/winter) - for some reason.

Which is annoying as I also have a main page in my website called Winter. (i.e. mywebsite.com/winter).

I have tried various versions of the COMMON, OPTIONAL and PRODUCT permalinks, but no matter what I type, [www.mywebsite.com/winter](http://www.mywebsite.com/winter) always points to the Woocommerce Shop page and not the normal website page.

Any ideas?

Huge thank you in advance :)
Steven

Comment: What does www.mywebsite.com/shop/seasons/winter give?

Comment: Also the Woocommerce shop page.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use this? This code stops WordPress from guessing where to go.

```
function no_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $header ){
    global $wp_query;

    if( is_404() )
        unset( $wp_query->query_vars['name'] );

    return $header;
}

add_filter( 'status_header', 'no_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

[Original answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242305/wordpress-custom-post-type-is-matching-on-partial-slug)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The issue is that my Woocommerce shop pages still seem to work even when the "category" part of the permalink is not entered.

i.e. mywebsite.com/winter (wrong) still goes to mywebsite.com/seasons/winter (correct).

Same applies to other pages within the shop - mywebsite.com/small (wrong) still opens the mywebsite.com/height/small (correct) page.